# Pig Latin terminal app in Rust

Tags: rust, pig-latin

I've started learning Rust a few days ago. This is the Pig Latin exercise from the [Rust Book](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch08-03-hash-maps.html#summary). The code works as expected. I have commented the logic of the program in the code.

My handling of `String`s is very hacky, as far as I know. To be honest, I mostly fiddled with it looking at error messages until the compiler was satisfied. I'd like to know what would be a idiomatic and may be more readable way to write it and if there as sane ways to optimize, especially the string manipulation part.

Thank you

````rs
use std::io;

fn main() {
    println!("Please enter a sentence:");

    const VOWELS: &str = "aeoiu";

    let mut sentence = String::new();
    io::stdin()
        .read_line(&mut sentence)
        .expect("An error occured");

    let mut words = sentence
        .split_whitespace()
        .map(|x| String::from(x))
        .collect::<Vec<String>>();

    for word in &mut words {
        if VOWELS.contains(word.chars().nth(0).unwrap().to_ascii_lowercase()) {
            // Starts with consonant:
            // The first consonant of each word is moved to the end of the word
            // and “ay” is added, so “first” becomes “irst-fay.”
            *word = format!("{}-hay", (*word).clone());
            // *word = (*word).clone() + "-" + "hay";
        } else {
            // Starts with a vowel:
            // Add “hay” to the end (“apple” becomes “apple-hay”).
            *word = format!(
                "{}-{}ay",
                String::from(&word[1..]),
                word.chars().nth(0).unwrap().to_string()
            );
            // String::from(&word[1..]) + "-" + &(word.chars().nth(0).unwrap().to_string()) + "ay";
        }
    }

    println!("{}", words.join(" "))
```
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wrote my comments in the new code:

```
fn main() {

    // I removed the input for simplicity
    let sentence = String::from("The elves are coming");

    // You don't need to collect to an intermediary vector and then mutate values inside
    // It is always nice if you can manage without mutating
    // It is also always good to split out big chunks of code into functions, here "pigifize". You can then debug or unit test that single function, for example
    let words = sentence
        .split_whitespace()
        .map(pigifize)
        .collect::<Vec<_>>();

    println!("{}", words.join(" "))
}

const VOWELS: &str = "aeoiu";

fn pigifize(word: &str) -> String {
    if word.is_empty() {
        // I don't know if this case can happen from split_whitespace, but just to get it out of the way (it makes the function more robust, should it get called in other cases)
        word.into()
    } else {
        // I removed your comments about the 2 cases because they were inverted. But they could be readded
        let first = word.chars().nth(0).unwrap();
        if VOWELS.contains(first.to_ascii_lowercase()) {
            format!("{}-hay", word) // format! can print string slices so you don't need to create String's as much
        } else {
            format!(
                "{}-{}ay",
                &word[1..],
                first
            )
        }
    }
}
```

Some example tests (they can help you while you develop the function too):

```
#[test]
fn pigifize_vowel() {
    assert_eq!(pigifize("unicorn"), "unicorn-hay")
}

#[test]
fn pigifize_consonant() {
    assert_eq!(pigifize("rhino"), "hino-ray")
}

#[test]
fn pigifize_empty() {
    assert_eq!(pigifize(""), "")
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer. Learned a lot :D